# My code will not show up the couts that its meant to do for each case ,c++!

Tags: c++

So I created a c++ program that is meant to give the user a different message depending on their grade and it always gives nothing. Please help.
http://pastebin.com/Xb81scqR

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{

   int grade;
   cout << "enter grade" <<endl;
   cin >> grade;

   switch(grade)
   {
   case 'A' :
      cout << "neat!" << endl;
      break;
   case 'B' :
       cout << "nice" <<endl;
   case 'C' :
      cout << "Poor" << endl;
      break;
   case 'D' :
      cout << "You passed atleast" << endl;
      break;
   case 'F' :
      cout << ":( bad" << endl;
      break;
   default :
      cout << "Invalid grade" << endl;
   }
   cout << "Your grade is " << grade << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declaer `grade` as a `char`, not an `int`, otherwise the `switch` will not work as you think.

Also, you are missing a `break` after

```
   case 'B' :
       cout << "nice" <<endl;
       break;                 // missing break
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare `grade` as `char`, not `int` as your switch requires character checking.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{

 char grade;     //   <--- this should be a char
cout << "enter grade" <<endl;
cin >> grade;

switch(grade)   //  <--- because here you are comparing grade with different characters 
{
case 'A' :
  cout << "neat!" << endl;
  break;
case 'B' :
   cout << "nice" <<endl;  
  break;    //  <---missing break
case 'C' :
  cout << "Poor" << endl;
  break;
case 'D' :
  cout << "You passed atleast" << endl;
  break;
case 'F' :
  cout << ":( bad" << endl;
  break;
default :
  cout << "Invalid grade" << endl;
}
cout << "Your grade is " << grade << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make `grade` `char`, but not for the reasons mentioned in other answers.

You cannot read character like "A" into `int`. Extraction `operator>>` fails and `grade` continues to be uninitialized, most probable to hit the default case. I'd initialize the grade to some value that'll not match any case, otherwise you'll rely on probability.

Don't forget that `break;`.